# Problem adding Android Bliss OS to GRUB

Tags: linux, partition, grub, android

Here's what's going on: I have an ACER laptop and it has Linux Mint, Ubuntu, Windows. It had an old Linux Mint Sarah partition that I reformatted into NTFS for a Bliss OS installation.

I went through with the installation on the partition and launched it once it was finished, all is well. After rebooting the computer, I don't see it in the GRUB menu. Okay, that happened before with other installations and I update-grub.

Reboot again and nothing.

I went into boot order because sometimes the partition might show there but there is nothing.

Next time I go to reinstall it shows that the partition /dev/sda7 has the Android installed. When I go into the disk utility on my Mint it also says the partition has android.

How do I add it to the GRUB menu and generally access it? (Also: Secure Boot is disabled in the Setup)

Comment: Better ask Bliss OS developers, no one here knows what that is and how it can be added to GRUB

Answer (score 1):

Formatting a partition as NTFS to boot android from makes little sense – I guess that's because some installation guide told you to use the NTFS partition that windows is on? Well, your Windows has an NTFS-capable bootloader, your GRUB doesn't; it has to chainload the Windows bootloader to load Windows from an NTFS partition.

So, format as ext4 instead, install on that. Then, tell grub's 10-os-probe script about it – my apologies if I can't help on that, don't know what that looks for in an android boot system.

https://docs.blissos.org/install-bliss-os/manual-install-on-linux describes manual installation on a Linux system including adding a Grub entry; I think you'll fare better with that than trying to make your system auto-detect stuff.

(Note: I do know how hard it is to write good documentation, and how little time you find for such things, but the bliss OS installation documentation is just... not very enlightening. It gives you steps without explaining any purpose (at best some command line options at times), so that if something doesn't work, it'll be hard to figure out what to do instead. I don't like it, but if you find the time, helping with documentation is universally highly appreciated in FOSS!)